# Need to know how to properly set UTF-8 in Python code

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have a writelog function in a script:

```
def writeLog(content):
    try:
        writeLineToFile(content,LOGFILE,'a')
    except:
        pass
    print(content)
```

This script used to work fine but lately is returning an encoding error:

```
  File "\\DataSource\Surveyor\PopulateFilenetDocumentsTable.py", line 216, in <module>
    writeLog("Updating document: " + row[field_names.index("doc_id")] + " with document id: " + (documentIdVal if documentIdVal else ""))
  File "\\DataSource\PopulateFilenetDocumentsTable.py", line 37, in writeLog
    print(content)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 110: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I change the code as such:

```
writeLog("Updating document: " + row[field_names.index("doc_id")] + " with document id: " + encode((documentIdVal if documentIdVal else "") ‘UTF-8’)
```

But it also returns a coding error.

Can someone tell me how to properly structure this line of code?

Comment: It looks like `writeLog` is opened to encode in `ascii`, which limits you to Unicode codepoints U+0000 to U+007F.  U+2013 is an `EN DASH` and outside that range.

Comment: error shows problem with `print()` and it can means you try to print it on console/terminal which don't have defined encoding. Or maybe you tried to redirect it to file and system doesn't know how to encode it to bytes - so it use standard `ascii`. You may try to encode text to `bytes` and send `bytes` with `sys.stdout.write()`

Comment: what is `writeLog` ? Is this your function? Show this code. Or maybe it is function from some module? What module?

Comment: @furas just added def writelog code to original post

Comment: but what is `writeLineToFile` and `LOGFILE` ? If  this is your function then show it and how you open file - you may need to use `encode='utf-8'`. If it is function from some module then what module it is.